# Importgraph lab hello world error

Tags: python, graphlab

After installing GraphLab in my PC which is running Ubuntu 14.04, I have just encountered the following error in my first hello world program:

```
import graphlab
```

**The Error:**

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-5-784beace7f26> in <module>()
  ----> 1 import graphlab

  ImportError: No module named graphlab
```

What is the reason for this and how the error could be solved?

Answer (score 1):

The usual reason for this type of error is that your package is installed somewhere other than on the default path that Python is searching.  Check

```
print sys.path
```

to see whether the location of your graphlab module is present. I'm guessing that it isn't, in which case you will need to append it:

```
sys.path.append('path/to/graphlab')
```

If that works you can then add that location to your PYTHONPATH for future use.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The problem occurred in both of my machines and it was solved via using: `source activate dato-env`. Is your suggestions addressing the same thing? Thanks

Comment: No, it sounds like you had installed graphlab in a virtual environment that you weren't actually using.  Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Did you install `graphlab` on your computer or did you install the `graphlab` python module? You might need to install the `graphlab` module if you only installed it on your computer.

Looks like [this link here](https://dato.com/download/install-graphlab-create-command-line.html) has the information that you need to install `graphlab` with `pip`.

Comment: Note: The link is now flagged as a dangerous site. FYI